# Spring Bean entry with Same Alias - one Child another Parent class

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

I have a requirement to Override a default service class with same Alias in SPRING bean.So that new service class is called with same Alias . I added the below code in Spring xml, here "CustomDefaultService extends DefaultService"

1) Does Spring give precedence to the child class in creating instance and referring via same alias name ?

2) Or its random for Spring if we have Child or parent to assign to same alias name?

```
<alias alias="modelService" name="customMefaultService" />
    <bean id="customMefaultService" class="com.tisl.CustomDefaultService" parent="defaultModelService">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which bean is actually used depends on the context loading order.
Spring will **use the last bean created**. So if you can ensure that the `customMefaultService` is created after the `DefaultService`.

To ensure the order you could use the [`depends-on`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-dependson). E.g:

```
<alias alias="modelService" name="customMefaultService" />
    <bean id="customMefaultService" class="com.tisl.CustomDefaultService" parent="defaultModelService" depends-on="defaultModelService">
</bean>
```

As you are already using `parent` I would assume that the order is already correct anyway.

Also make sure that [`setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.html#setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding-boolean-) is set to `true` (should be as `true` is the default)

Comment: Thanks LazerBass, How I can ensure that the customMefaultService is created after the DefaultService ?